# I2C Bus Routing

Tags: i2c

I wanted to know if I can run I2C Bus lines parallel.

I have to connect three ADS122C04, five MCP9600, and one INA260 in a two-layer PCB since PCB price is a concern.

What is the minimum distance I need to leave between the lines?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the bus frequency of I2C?

Comment: What is the lentgh of the bus?

Comment: The frequency is the standard 100kHz and I don't know for sure what is the entire length but all the components fit in a 118*81mm PCB, maybe the length is a bit less than 200mm

Comment: 100kHz allows for 1000ns rise time but fall time is max 300ns. What value pull-up resistances there are? Are there series resistors and what is their value? Do you have an estimate of track capacitance to ground or other surroundings? At least the maximum allowable capacitance is 400pF but it again depends on the resistances.

Comment: I've used 2.2k resistors for pull-up and I haven't used series resistors. Is there an easy way to estimate the track capacitance?

Comment: Which PCB design software you are using? Some can calculate them for you. There are also many tools that can calculate the capacitance, given that the parameters (track length, width, PCB material and thickness etc) are plugged in.

Comment: I'm using KICAD. I've tried using online calculators but they only give me the impedance.